# how to use np.transpose() for the shape of (1, 7, 7, 1024)

Tags: python, numpy

`a = np.ones((1, 7, 7, 1024))`

I want to change the shape to (1, 1024, 7, 7)

I saw the tutorial on Numpy website, I thought it needs to set the position respectively.
So I used the code below.

`shape_ = np.transpose(a, (0, 2, 3, 1))`

When I print the shape:

The shape will be:
`(1, 7, 1024, 7)`

I can't figure the reasons cause this.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: With `0,3,1,2`, axis 0 stays put, axis 3 is next, axis 1 and 2 are just moved over (they could be switched if you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
shape_ = np.transpose(a, (0, 3, 2, 1))
```

It gives the following when printing the output:

```
(1, 1024, 7, 7)
```

0 is the first axis, 1 is the second, 2 is the third and so on depending on your amount of axis, so you just permute them as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, but I still cannot figure out why I can't use (0, 2, 3, 1), isn't it the same?

Comment: If (1, 7, 7, 1024) = (0, 1, 2, 3) so 1024 = 3.
So where would you place 3 if you want (1, 1024, 7, 7)?
So this is all the combinations:
(3, 1, 2, 0) which gives (1024, 7, 7, 1), 
(0, 3, 2, 1) which gives (1, 1024, 7, 7), 
(0, 1, 3, 2) which gives  (1, 7, 1024, 7), 
(0, 1, 2, 3) which gives (1, 7, 7, 1024). 
You might want to explain why you think what you are doing should give the desired result?

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot!